# Calling classmethod multiple times in python

Tags: python-3.x, class-method

I am trying to create a classmethod which can be called again and again, however it only works once and stops. Here is the code:

```
class NewBytes(bytes):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var= var

    @classmethod
    def rip(cls):
        return cls(var[2:])

a = b"12asd5789"
x = NewBytes(a)

print(x, x.rip(), x.rip().rip(), x.rip().rip().rip())
```

Here is what I got from this:

```
b'12asd5789' b'asd5789' b'asd5789' b'asd5789'
```

However, what I want to have is:

```
b'12asd5789' b'asd5789' b'd5789' b'789'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't actually want a class method, since you need access to instance state here.

```
class NewBytes(bytes):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def rip(self):
        return type(self)(self.x[2:])
```

Comment: wow it works very nicely. I've never thought that you could get class like that, clever way to do it. One more thing what if I would want to update x value as well? Let's say ripped data first 2 bytes become the value "x". Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but not advisable. Methods should either return a new value, or mutate the object, preferably not doing *both*.

Comment: Even so, could you please update the answer to that way? That would be great

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't make it work. It just returns same value as x. The syntax that I should be using is different maybe?

Comment: Oh right, yep I made a mistake. I don't think you can do it sanely, because bytes are immutable. The same reason you can't change the number 4 into the number 5.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But, I thought that strings are mutable, it appears they are not as well. Only with a list, I think this can be done, and I think this is the sane way of doing it, lol. Anyway it was nice to learn, thank you

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer of using `self.x` doesnt make sense since this is a class method (too quick to answer). I think this is a case of the XY problem, see the below example of how to use a class method.

```
class Test(object):
    x = "hey there whats up this is a long string"

    @classmethod
    def TestFunction(cls):
        cls.x = cls.x[3:]
        print(cls.x)


print(Test().x)
Test().TestFunction()
Test().TestFunction()
Test().TestFunction()
Test().TestFunction()
Test().TestFunction()
```

Comment: doesn't work "self is not defined". It is a @classmethod so no self

Comment: I think that I shouldn't use classmethod as wim stated. Plus, x is an input, and when I try to cls.x it says its not defined.

Comment: Yes I also agree, however I was merely trying to answer your question. Check out The XY problem...